# System IO Exception Cannot access since already used by another process

Tags: c#

I read multiple forums and solutions but none helped me resolve. Please let me know the the flaw in the following piece of code.

```
public static void WriteLogFile(string writedata)
    {
        string path = @"C:\Example.txt";
        if (!File.Exists(path))
        {
            File.Create(path);
            TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(path);
            tw.WriteLine(writedata);
            //tw.Close();
        }
        else if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            using (var tw = new StreamWriter(path, true))
            {
                tw.WriteLine(writedata);
                //tw.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you use ``using ()`` in the ``else if`` block and not in the ``if``?

Comment: Change `File.Create(path);` to `File.Create(path).Dispose();`

Comment: @Equalsk or just remove the line as a whole, StreamWriter will create the file if it doesnt exist

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that off the top of my head :-)

Comment: i tried the suggested option still the same error

Answer (score 1):

Thats all you need.

```
public static void WriteLogFile(string writedata)
{
    string path = @"C:\Example.txt";
    using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(path, true))
        tw.WriteLine(writedata);
}
```

Have a look at the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter(v=vs.110).aspx)

You will find, with the constructor `StreamWriter(string, boolean)`

> Initializes a new instance of the StreamWriter class for the specified file by using the default encoding and buffer size. If the file exists, it can be either overwritten or appended to. If the file does not exist, this constructor creates a new file.

**FYI, since your method is called `WriteLogFile`, pls dont re-invent the wheel and use a logging library like log4net.**

**Edit**, proof that its working
[image]

**Edit 2**, change your code to the following, to fix multi-threaded scenario:

```
private static readonly object _syncLock = new object();
public static void WriteLogFile(string writedata)
{
    lock (_syncLock)
    {
        string path = @"C:\rfa\Example.txt";
        using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(path, true))
            tw.WriteLine(writedata);
    }
}
```

This is the result, notice that now the numbers arent in order:
[image]

Comment: @NewLearner than you are doing something you didnt mention, the code works fine.

Comment: @NewLearner Are you maybe calling the method in a multi-threaded scenario?

Comment: @NewLearner **sarcastic question incoming** and what are you doing to prevent from 2 threads calling the method at the same time, where the second thread gives the exception?

Comment: @NewLearner see my 2nd Edit

Comment: @NewLearner no problem, but pls take the following sentence into account: **FYI, since your method is called ``WriteLogFile``, pls dont re-invent the wheel and use a logging library like log4net.** - not a single person on this planet should write his own logging mechanism, there are so many good and free ones out there